# Pipe Translater in Html Element

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, pipe, element

So, dont know if anyone can help me. I have the below line of code in html :

```
<ion-item class="item-style">
  <ion-label>{{ 'SettingsPage.ChangeLanguage' | translate }}</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" (ionChange)="onLanguageChange();" cancelText={{cancelText}} okText={{okText}}>
    <ion-select-option value="en">{{ 'SettingsPage.English' | translate }}</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="mt">{{ 'SettingsPage.Maltese' | translate }}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

and the following methods in the .ts :

```
 onLanguageChange() {
this.translate.use(this.language);
console.log(this.language);
this.globalVariableService.languageChanged = true;
this.globalVariableService.setCurrentLanguage(this.language);
this.storage.set('Language', this.language).then(() => {
  this.sectorDataServiceProvider.populateSectorData().then(data => {
    console.log('this.sectorInfo ', this.sectorDataServiceProvider.sectorInfo);
  });
});
this.setOkAndCancelText();
```

}

```
setOkAndCancelText() {
    if (this.language === 'en') {
      this.cancelText = 'Cancel';
      this.okText = 'OK';
    } else if (this.language === 'mt') {
      this.cancelText = 'Le';
      this.okText = 'Iva';
    }
  }
```

I wish to remove the s setOkAndCancelText() which is being used to fill the cancelText={{cancelText}} parameter when the language changes within the app, and have something similar to:

```
<p [innerHTML]="'TermsOfUsePage.Header' | translate"></p>
```

Any ideas how i can make this possible please?

Comment: I usually don't recommend libraries as a solutino, but I believe this would be exactly what you're looking for : https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader

Comment: Yes i am already using that library, the problem is that I cant seem to find a way how to use the translater pipe in a parameter as the example above.  Because i am already using it this way
 <ion-label>{{ 'SettingsPage.ChangeLanguage' | translate }}</ion-label>

Comment: Could you please elaborate your code? I will need your component html, ts and module.

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: i changed the question and made it more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done it in following ways:

- Installed the following packages:

> "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1"
>
> "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",

- In app.module.js, add the following in imports:

> ```
>  TranslateModule.forRoot({
>           loader: {
>             provide: TranslateLoader,
>             useFactory: AppHttpLoaderFactory,
>             deps: [HttpClient]
>           }
>         }),
>
> export function AppHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
>   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, Environment.frontend('/assets/i18n/'), '.json');
> }
> ```

Here we have kept our en.json file under i18n folder where all key values of text are there.

After this you can use it in html template:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" (ionChange)="onLanguageChange();" cancelText={{'cancel.text' | translate }} okText={{okText}/>
```

Here **cancel.text** is a key in en.json file.

Comment: Solved it Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reliaing on libraries, you can create your custom service and add your local strings i.e key and value as following:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalizationService {
    localizedStrings: any;

    constructor() {
        this.localizedStrings = {
            en: {
                SettingsPage: {
                    cancelText: 'Cancel'
                }
            },
            mt: {
                SettingsPage: {
                    cancelText: 'Le'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getResource(keyString: string, workingLanguage: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let resourceValue = null;
            if(this.localizedStrings[workingLanguage].hasOwnProperty(keyString)) {
                resourceValue = this.localizedStrings[workingLanguage][keyString];
            } else {
                resourceValue = this.getPropertyByKeyPath(this.localizedStrings[workingLanguage], keyString);
                // if(!resourceValue) {
                //     debugger;
                // }
            }

            if(resourceValue) {
                resolve(resourceValue);
            } else {
                resolve(keyString);
            }
        });        
    }

    private getPropertyByKeyPath(targetObj, keyPath) { 
        var keys = keyPath.split('.');
        if(keys.length == 0) return undefined; 

        keys = keys.reverse();
        var subObject = targetObj;
        while(keys.length) {
            var k = keys.pop();
            if(!subObject.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                subObject = subObject[k];
            }
        }
        return subObject;
    }  
}
```

Note that it is flexible, you can go deeper in objects. Now simply create a pipe for this service:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

import { LocalizationService } from '../shared/localization.service';

    @Pipe({
      name:"translate"
    })
    export class LocalizedResourcePipe {
        constructor(private localizationService: LocalizationService) {

        }

        transform(resourceKey: string, workingLanguage: string) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if(!resourceKey) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    this.localizationService.getResource(resourceKey, workingLanguage)
                    .then((value) => {
                        resolve(value); 
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now simply call it in your HTML:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" (ionChange)="onLanguageChange();" cancelText={{'SettingsPage.cancelText' | translate: 'en' | async}} okText={{'SettingsPage.cancelText' | translate: 'en' | async}}>
```

You can could make the the language parameter dynamic as well and in pipe, give it a default value. anyway here is the way to call it for your other language:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" (ionChange)="onLanguageChange();" cancelText={{'SettingsPage.cancelText' | translate: 'mt' | async}} okText={{'SettingsPage.cancelText' | translate: 'mt' | async}}>
```

Comment: cancelText={{'SettingsPage.Cancel' | translate } it turned to red and an error shows up. and when i try out like: cancelText="{{'SettingsPage.Cancel' | translate }}" doesnt work still

Comment: you need to pass the language. `cancelText="{{'SettingsPage.Cancel' | translate: 'en' }}` notice the `translate: 'en' `

Comment: Solved it Thank you :)

Comment: Just a tip, instead of passing language everytime, weite a ligic to get the current language inside the pipe....and make this language parameter optional ;)

Comment: Thanks :) I did that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852071/ngx-translate-in-ts-file-angular

Can anyone help me with this question too?

Comment: @JoanneFsadni use my implementation, then it will work for your both requirements. I posted answer for you.

Comment: What I am trying to do is remove code not add more :) So if what I have is the shortest I can go, then i will leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-language-with-translate-pipe)

Translate Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class TranslateService {
  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  use(lang: string): Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise<{}>((resolve, reject) => {
      const langPath = `assets/languageFiles/${lang || 'en'}.json`;
      this.http.get<{}>(langPath).subscribe(
        translation => {
          this.data = Object.assign({}, translation || {});
          resolve(this.data);
        },
        error => {
          this.data = {};
          resolve(this.data);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Translate Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from './translate.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
  pure:false
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
  transform(key: any): any {
    return this.translate.data[key] || key;
  }

}
```