# NGX Translate in .Ts File - Angular

Tags: angular, translate

Currently I have this method in one of my .ts files:

```
 clearFavourites() {
    if (this.language === 'en') {
      this.dialogs.confirm('Do you want to clear your favourite apps?', 'Clear Favourites', ['Yes', 'No'])
        .then(val => {
          console.log('Dialog dismissed' + val);
          if (val === 1) {
            this.resetFavIcons();
            this.storage.remove('FavAppList');
            this.storage.set('FavHasChanged', 'yes');
          }
        })
        .catch(e =>
          console.log('Error displaying dialog', e)
        );
    } else if (this.language === 'mt') {
      this.dialogs.confirm('Trid tneħħi l-apps tiegħek mill-favoriti?', 'Neħħi minn Favoriti', ['Iva', 'Le'])
        .then(val => {
          console.log('Dialog dismissed' + val);
          if (val === 1) {
            this.resetFavIcons();
            this.storage.remove('FavAppList');
            this.storage.set('FavHasChanged', 'yes');
          }
        })
        .catch(e =>
          console.log('Error displaying dialog', e)
        );
    }
  }
}
```

I already have ngx trasnlate installed and i am already using the translate pipe in html. 
I would like to use the same for this method to remove the if and else for checking the language and just have something similar to:

```
clearFavourites() {
    this.dialogs.confirm('SettingsPage.RemoveFav' | translate, 'SettingsPage.ClearFav' | translate, ['SettingsPage.Yes' | translate, 'SettingsPage.No' | translate])
        .then(val => {
          console.log('Dialog dismissed' + val);
          if (val === 1) {
            this.resetFavIcons();
            this.storage.remove('FavAppList');
            this.storage.set('FavHasChanged', 'yes');
          }
        })
        .catch(e =>
          console.log('Error displaying dialog', e)
        );
    }
}
```

The above method is not working for me, is there another way I can use the ngx translate pipe in a .ts file similar to the method above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find an answer to my question.

I changed my code to:

```
  clearFavourites() {
    this.dialogs.confirm(this.translate.instant('SettingsPage.AskFavs'), this.translate.instant('SettingsPage.ClearFavs'), [this.translate.instant('SettingsPage.Yes'), this.translate.instant('SettingsPage.No')])
      .then(val => {
        console.log('Dialog dismissed' + val);
        if (val === 1) {
          this.resetFavIcons();
          this.storage.remove('FavAppList');
          this.storage.set('FavHasChanged', 'yes');
        }
      })
      .catch(e =>
        console.log('Error displaying dialog', e)
      );
  }
}
```

and managed to get a dynamic text translation in a ts file.

Hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58836242/859968) answer, you can inject the service like following:

```
constructor(private localizationSvc: LocalizationService) {
}
```

and then you can use the `getResource` method to get your resources in component:

```
const translatedText = await this.localizationSvc.getResource('SettingsPage.cancelText', 'en');
```

***Note***: This answer is based upon last answer i referenced above. So make sure to copy code from there.