# Angular 7 ngx-translate change run time transaltion without refresh page

Tags: translate, devextreme, ngx-translate, devextreme-angular

**Notes:** I tired all questions & answers related to this topic.

**I want to Translate Typescript variable Value without refresh page on change language Dropdown .**

I trying To change the language-wise data change. I success to change to **`HTML Bind:`** value on dropdown value change but not update **`TypeScript Bind:`** value.

i use [**ngx-translate**](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

**I referer Links: but not success**

1. [angular-ngx-translate-usage-in-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870513/angular-ngx-translate-usage-in-typescript)
2. [ngx-translate-in-ts-file-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852071/ngx-translate-in-ts-file-angular)
3. [ngx-translate-with-dynamic-text-on-ts-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155989/ngx-translate-with-dynamic-text-on-ts-file)

**`components.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-translate',
  templateUrl: './translate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./translate.component.css']
})
export class TranslateComponent implements OnInit {
  typeScriptvalue: string;
  simpleProducts:any[]=[ {   
    name:'English',
    id:'en'
  },
  {   
    name:'French',
    id:'fr'
  }];

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.typeScriptvalue = this.translate.instant('HOME.TITLE');
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  changeevent(e)
  {
    console.log(e);
    this.translate.use(e.value);

  }

}
```

**`component.html`**

```
 <label><b> HTML Bind</b></label> : <div>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</div> <br>
    <label><b>TypeScript Bind</b></label> : <div>{{ typeScriptvalue }}</div> <br>
    <label>
        Change language : <div class="dx-field-value">
            <dx-select-box  [dataSource]="simpleProducts" displayExpr="name" valueExpr="id" (onValueChanged)="changeevent($event)"></dx-select-box>
        </div>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research I have finally got the best solution.

---

**You can reassign the Typescript variable on the subscriber method.** [use method](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

```
 changeevent(e)
  {
    console.log(e);
    this.translate.use(e.value).subscribe(data => {
      this.typeScriptvalue = this.translate.instant('Home.Title');      
    });

  }
```

Comment: But did you find the problem ? why it doesn't gets translated ?! maybe it is related to some third party components ?!